# Is this the right place to ask about mathematical notation?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, questions

For instance, I'm looking for symbols for the following ternary relations:

1. *f* is a relation with source *X* and target *Y*.
2. *f* is a left-total relation with *ditto*
3. *f* is a right-total relation with *ditto*
4. *f* is a left-and-right total relation with *ditto*

There's more (I'm looking for 16 different symbols, in total), but I won't list them all here. Anyway, is the TeX forum a good place to ask?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The TeX site is not the correct place. It would be, if you would know your desired notation and ask how to typeset this with TeX.

For the notation style itself, better ask on the [Math](https://math.stackexchange.com/) or [Graphicdesign](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) site. The latter also deals with [typography questions](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40151/typography).